# Bank account balance, withdraw, deposit: compartmentalize without losing functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a better way to write this while maintaining its current functionality? (checking balances, updating, subtracting, etc...) If so, where would I begin? I saw a code briefly in class that was for a similar questions and it looked more streamlined.

```
class Account:

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, name, account_number, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.balance = balance

    # returns string representation of object
    def __str__(self):
        return"Account Name: {0}\nAccount Number: {1} \nAccount Balance:\
    ${2:.2f}".format(self.name, self.account_number, self.balance)

    # add given amount to balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    # subtract amount and fee from balance
    def withdraw(self, amount, fee):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount - fee

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # make 3 objects
    acct1 = Account('Guy Mann', 90453889, 100)
    acct2 = Account('Donald Duck', 83504837, 100)
    acct3 = Account('Joe Smith', 74773321, 100)

    # print
    print(acct1)
    print(acct2)
    print(acct3)

    # deposit and print
    acct1.deposit(25.85)
    acct2.deposit(75.50)
    acct3.deposit(50)
    print(acct1)
    print(acct2)
    print(acct3)

    # withdraw and print
    acct1.withdraw(25.85, 2.50)
    acct2.withdraw(75.50, 1.50)
    acct3.withdraw(50, 2)
    print(acct1)
    print(acct2)
    print(acct3)
```

Comment: Now it's looking good :-)

Comment: Awesome! Now what about simplifying this code? Is it doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is already quite compact. Some [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code styling will not hurt. Some spaces here and there, consistency in using quotes in string literals. Also some comments can be turned into [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). (and comment like "constructor" is not necessary - everyone who knows Python will recognize that).

However, one thing probably good to make sure: The balance better use proper type, for example, [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html). Float is terribly wrong type for monetary transactions.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance and taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Roman's answer in that the code is already compact. In it's current configuration though, it is not very scalable. There is a lot of [duplicate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code) in `__main__`, and you could replace the `Account` creation statements with a dictionary of tuples and a for-loop. Then you could store the `Account` instances back into a dictionary. Using a dictionary would allow you to reference the accounts by the name of the holder rather than by free-standing variables, which seems semantically cleaner.

Additionally, the `print` statements could be replaced with a for-loop as well.

These modifications may not reduce the number of lines in the code as is, but if you consider a case where you wanted to make 100 `Account`s and print information about them, then the approach above may be better.

Answer (score 3):

The `__str__` method can be simplified a bit. Already with a normal format string you do not need to specify the index of the object to format if it is just sequentially:

```
"Account Name: {}\nAccount Number: {}\nAccount Balance: ${:.2f}".format(self.name, self.account_number, self.balance)
```

You could also use dictionary lookup:

```
"Account Name: {self.name}\nAccount Number: {self.account_number} \nAccount Balance: ${self.balance:.2f}".format(self=self)
```

And then you could use the relatively new [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Python 3.6+), making it a bit shorter:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"Account Name: {self.name}\nAccount Number: {self.account_number}\nAccount Balance: ${self.balance:.2f}"
```

And then, finally, use a multiline string to make it fit into 80 character lines:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"""Account Name: {self.name}
Account Number: {self.account_number}
Account Balance: ${self.balance:.2f}"""
```